# ReactJS + Material-UI: How to reduce column width of Material-UI's <TableRow/>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently using ReactJS + Material-UI, and with the Material-UI's `<Table>`, the columns width are automatically set depending on content. Currently it seems to enforce equal width on all columns, but I want some columns to take up more width than others.

So is there a way to arbitrarily assign width of `<TableRow>`'s column and still be dynamic based on content instead?

Answer (score 7):

You can set the style of the TableHeaderColumn and its corresponding TableRowColumns. Below I set width to 12 pixels (and background color to yellow just to further demo custom styling)

working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0zh1yfqt/1/

```
const {
  Table,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  TableRowColumn,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  getMuiTheme,
} = MaterialUI;

 class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const customColumnStyle = { width: 12, backgroundColor: 'yellow' };

    return (
      <div>
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHeaderColumn>A</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn style={customColumnStyle}>B</TableHeaderColumn>
              <TableHeaderColumn>C</TableHeaderColumn>
            </TableRow>            
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>2</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>5</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>6</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>7</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn style={customColumnStyle}>8</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>9</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Example />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: but that is hardcoded width, correct? I was looking for one that dynamically would change based on the content but still have wider width than other columns.

Comment: You can additionally use whiteSpace: 'nowrap', and/or minWidth/maxWidth

Comment: could you show the full code along with the whiteSpace?

Comment: Is your content one line of text, or can it wrap?

Comment: Could you show both cases? Because, when the window is minimized, the content actually gets wrapped.

Comment: If you don't want wrapping, you can just do: const customColumnStyle = { width: 12, backgroundColor: 'yellow', whiteSpace: 'nowrap' };  If you actually want it to wrap, but only if it gets rather large, then instead add "maxWidth: 400" or whatever width in pixels you want to limit the width to.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hidden prop in the `<Table>` component that makes it behave like a HTML `<table>` element, i.e. adapt the column widths to the content:

```
<Table style={{ tableLayout: 'auto' }} fixedHeader={false} ...>
    ...
</Table>
```

It doesn't let you style columns one by one, but at least it's less ugly than large columns for small contents by default.

Comment: This is great, but beware that it also causes the table to overflow the edge of the screen and become invisible if it becomes too wide/the window becomes too narrow. More interesting commentary in [this thread](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1911).

Answer (score -1):

according to the answer of @François Zaninotto @Lane Rettig

...

and adding with this ,you can get a scroll table with infinite columns...

```
componentDidMount() {
    let tbody = $(this.refs.table)
    if (tbody && tbody.length == 1) {
        let div = tbody[0].refs.tableDiv
        div.style.overflowX = 'auto'
        div.parentElement.style.overflowX = 'hidden'
    } else {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with column width